# Apache POI will not set superscript inside a TextBox

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to use Apache POI(4.1.1) to write some text inside a textbox (or rectangle shape), and this text must have superscripts in it.  I can get this to work for data inside a cell, but not when using a textbox.  Here is a minimal example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class SuperScriptTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.createSheet("Sheet 1");

        XSSFFont fontInfo = wb.createFont();
        fontInfo.setFontName("Arial");
        fontInfo.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);

        XSSFFont fontInfoSuperscript = wb.createFont();
        fontInfoSuperscript.setFontName("Arial");
        fontInfoSuperscript.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
        fontInfoSuperscript.setTypeOffset(Font.SS_SUPER);
        fontInfoSuperscript.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

        Row row = ws.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

        // Writing to a cell produces desired results:
        XSSFRichTextString richString = new XSSFRichTextString("Level3");
        richString.applyFont(fontInfo);
        richString.applyFont(5, 6, fontInfoSuperscript);
        cell.setCellValue(richString);

        // Writing to a textbox does not:
        XSSFDrawing drawing = ws.createDrawingPatriarch();
        XSSFTextBox txtBox = drawing.createTextbox(new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 7));
        XSSFRichTextString richString2 = new XSSFRichTextString("Level3");
        richString2.applyFont(fontInfo);
        richString2.applyFont(5, 6, fontInfoSuperscript);
        txtBox.setText(richString2);

        try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Superscript.xlsx")) {
            wb.write(fileOut);
        }
    }
}
```

The cell will give me the right font and size, and properly superscript the 3 and turn it red.
The textbox will give me the correct font and size, and will color the 3, but it will not superscript the 3.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Excel` cells and text box shapes have different kinds of font settings. For `Excel` cells spreadsheet settings are used while for text box shapes drawing settings are used.

Because `XSSFRichTextString` mostly gets used for `Excel` cell values and shared strings, it internally uses spreadsheet settings. When it comes to `XSSFRichTextString`s in context of shapes, the settings need to be converted. This is done in [XSSFSimpleShape.setText(XSSFRichTextString str)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_2/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSimpleShape.java?view=markup#l448) using the method [XSSFSimpleShape.applyAttributes(CTRPrElt pr, CTTextCharacterProperties rPr)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_2/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSimpleShape.java?view=markup#l948).

In spreadsheet settings `CTRPrElt` there is a `CTVerticalAlignFontProperty` used to set baseline, superscript or subscript. In drawing settings `CTTextCharacterProperties` there is a `baseline` attrtibute used which is `0` for baseline, `+n%` for superscript and `-n%` for subscript. There `n%` is the distance from the baseline.

Until now the `XSSFSimpleShape.applyAttributes` lacks converting `CTVerticalAlignFontProperty` to `CTTextCharacterProperties.setBaseline`. To get this, one could patching  `XSSFSimpleShape.applyAttributes` like so:

```
private static void applyAttributes(CTRPrElt pr, CTTextCharacterProperties rPr) {
...

    if (pr.sizeOfVertAlignArray() > 0) {
        CTVerticalAlignFontProperty vertAlign = pr.getVertAlignArray(0);
        if (vertAlign.getVal() == STVerticalAlignRun.BASELINE) {
             rPr.setBaseline(0);
        } else if (vertAlign.getVal() == STVerticalAlignRun.SUPERSCRIPT) {
             rPr.setBaseline(30000); //30% distance from baseline == default superscript
        } else if (vertAlign.getVal() == STVerticalAlignRun.SUBSCRIPT) {
             rPr.setBaseline(-25000); //-25% distance from baseline == default subscript
        }
    }
}
```

For superscript 30% distance from baseline is choosen because that is the default when someone ticks text effect superscript in text box font settings. For subscript -25% distance from baseline is choosen because that is the default when someone ticks text effect subscript   in text box font settings.

Complete example having own `setText` and `applyAttributes` to show that it works:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class SuperScriptTest {

    static void setText(XSSFSimpleShape shape, XSSFRichTextString str) {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) shape.getDrawing().getParent().getParent();
        //str.setStylesTableReference(wb.getStylesSource()); // cannot be done here since XSSFRichTextString.setStylesTableReference has protected access

        CTTextParagraph p = CTTextParagraph.Factory.newInstance();
        if (str.numFormattingRuns() == 0) {
            CTRegularTextRun r = p.addNewR();
            CTTextCharacterProperties rPr = r.addNewRPr();
            rPr.setLang("en-US");
            rPr.setSz(1100);
            r.setT(str.getString());

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.getCTRst().sizeOfRArray(); i++) {
                CTRElt lt = str.getCTRst().getRArray(i);
                CTRPrElt ltPr = lt.getRPr();
                if (ltPr == null) {
                    ltPr = lt.addNewRPr();
                }

                CTRegularTextRun r = p.addNewR();
                CTTextCharacterProperties rPr = r.addNewRPr();
                rPr.setLang("en-US");

                applyAttributes(ltPr, rPr);

                r.setT(lt.getT());
            }
        }

        //clearText(); //replaced by it's code, 3 lines below
        shape.getTextParagraphs().clear();
        CTTextBody txBody = shape.getCTShape().getTxBody();
        txBody.setPArray(null); // remove any existing paragraphs

        CTShape ctShape = shape.getCTShape();
        ctShape.getTxBody().setPArray(new CTTextParagraph[] { p });
        //shape.getTextParagraphs().add(new XSSFTextParagraph(ctShape.getTxBody().getPArray(0), ctShape)); // cannot be done here since XSSFTextParagraph contructor is not public
    }

    static void applyAttributes(CTRPrElt pr, CTTextCharacterProperties rPr) {

        if (pr.sizeOfBArray() > 0) {
            rPr.setB(pr.getBArray(0).getVal());
        }
        if (pr.sizeOfUArray() > 0) {
            STUnderlineValues.Enum u1 = pr.getUArray(0).getVal();
            if (u1 == STUnderlineValues.SINGLE) {
                rPr.setU(STTextUnderlineType.SNG);
            } else if (u1 == STUnderlineValues.DOUBLE) {
                rPr.setU(STTextUnderlineType.DBL);
            } else if (u1 == STUnderlineValues.NONE) {
                rPr.setU(STTextUnderlineType.NONE);
            }
        }
        if (pr.sizeOfIArray() > 0) {
            rPr.setI(pr.getIArray(0).getVal());
        }

        if (pr.sizeOfRFontArray() > 0) {
            CTTextFont rFont = rPr.isSetLatin() ? rPr.getLatin() : rPr.addNewLatin();
            rFont.setTypeface(pr.getRFontArray(0).getVal());
        }

        if (pr.sizeOfSzArray() > 0) {
            int sz = (int) (pr.getSzArray(0).getVal() * 100);
            rPr.setSz(sz);
        }

        if (pr.sizeOfColorArray() > 0) {
            CTSolidColorFillProperties fill = rPr.isSetSolidFill() ? rPr.getSolidFill() : rPr.addNewSolidFill();
            org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTColor xlsColor = pr.getColorArray(0);
            if (xlsColor.isSetRgb()) {
                CTSRgbColor clr = fill.isSetSrgbClr() ? fill.getSrgbClr() : fill.addNewSrgbClr();
                clr.setVal(xlsColor.getRgb());
            } else if (xlsColor.isSetIndexed()) {
                HSSFColor indexed = HSSFColor.getIndexHash().get((int) xlsColor.getIndexed());
                if (indexed != null) {
                    byte[] rgb = new byte[3];
                    rgb[0] = (byte) indexed.getTriplet()[0];
                    rgb[1] = (byte) indexed.getTriplet()[1];
                    rgb[2] = (byte) indexed.getTriplet()[2];
                    CTSRgbColor clr = fill.isSetSrgbClr() ? fill.getSrgbClr() : fill.addNewSrgbClr();
                    clr.setVal(rgb);
                }
            }
        }

        if (pr.sizeOfVertAlignArray() > 0) {
            CTVerticalAlignFontProperty vertAlign = pr.getVertAlignArray(0);
            if (vertAlign.getVal() == STVerticalAlignRun.BASELINE) {
                 rPr.setBaseline(0);
            } else if (vertAlign.getVal() == STVerticalAlignRun.SUPERSCRIPT) {
                 rPr.setBaseline(30000); //30% distance from baseline == default superscript
            } else if (vertAlign.getVal() == STVerticalAlignRun.SUBSCRIPT) {
                 rPr.setBaseline(-25000); //-25% distance from baseline == default subscript
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.createSheet("Sheet 1");

        XSSFFont fontInfo = wb.createFont();
        fontInfo.setFontName("Arial");
        fontInfo.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);

        XSSFFont fontInfoSuperscript = wb.createFont();
        fontInfoSuperscript.setFontName("Arial");
        fontInfoSuperscript.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
        fontInfoSuperscript.setTypeOffset(Font.SS_SUPER);
        //fontInfoSuperscript.setTypeOffset(Font.SS_SUB);
        fontInfoSuperscript.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

        Row row = ws.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

        // Writing to a cell produces desired results:
        XSSFRichTextString richString = new XSSFRichTextString("Level3");
        richString.applyFont(fontInfo);
        richString.applyFont(5, 6, fontInfoSuperscript);
        cell.setCellValue(richString);

        // Writing to a textbox does not:
        XSSFDrawing drawing = ws.createDrawingPatriarch();
        XSSFTextBox txtBox = drawing.createTextbox(new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 7));
        XSSFRichTextString richString2 = new XSSFRichTextString("Level3");
        richString2.applyFont(fontInfo);
        richString2.applyFont(5, 6, fontInfoSuperscript);
        //txtBox.setText(richString2);
        setText(txtBox, richString2);

        try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Superscript.xlsx")) {
            wb.write(fileOut);
        }
    }
}
```